# .htaccess doesnt seem to work well in my mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller

So I followed an MVC tutorial in youtube at first everything was going well, but when I start configuring the `.htaccess` file i does not seem to work! I think I'm going crazy with this problem I've been researching and every solution they provide does not work on me,

This link works

```
localhost/myApp/public/?url=home
```

but then i put it this way

```
localhost/myApp/public/home
```

It causing not found error, I tried a lot of suggested solution but still I get this error.

This was my `.htaccess` before I made some changes;

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=?$1 [QSA,L]
```

And I tried something like this

```
Options  -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/html/myApp/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm banging my head in the wall for a couple of hours now i hope someone can enlighten me thanks.

Comment: You're making too many changes at once. Set the file back to what it was originally. Verify that it works. Make one change, if it breaks, Google that till you understand how it is supposed to work. If you can't figure it out come back here and ask a question specifically about that one thing.

Comment: I already change it back, still i get 404 error.

Comment: Then either you made a mistake in setting it back or else this isn't the problem. Start over with your youtube tutorial and create a new project then diff the old and new project to see what the differences are.

Comment: I already did, I created 3 different project still i get this error.

Comment: So when you follow the tutorial from beginning to end do you have a working project before you start to modify it?

Comment: I wasn't able to finish it because I'm obviously stuck with this part which is the routing. I cant proceed.

Comment: did you configure your apache wamp server for `.htaccess` if not [check this](http://www.bsourcecode.com/php/how-to-enable-htaccess-in-wamp-server/) and don't forget to restart your server. i.e wamp for windows

Comment: Never mind i was able to solve it thanks to StillLearnin.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the answer for people who find this question later. If you don't want to post an answer, then delete the question since no one else has come up with an answer.